# How to format a Gmail filter that contains 2, or more, two-argument statements

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

###### If I want to maintain one Gmail filter for multiple "2 or more argument" statements how is this formatted?

###### Something like this...

```
<to:john@aol.com AND list:(<123456.xt.local>)> OR <to:peter@aol.com AND list:(<7891011.xt.local>)>
```

1. For each statement, that contains two arguments, we need an "AND" which means brackets`()` ... correct?
2. Between each construct we need an "OR" which means curly braces `{}` ... correct?

Shouldn't this statement work?

```
{(to:john@aol.com list:(<123456.xt.local>))} {(to:peter@aol.com list:(<7891011.xt.local>))}
```

**I am getting a warning that my filter contains characters that cause issues.**

> Filter searches that contain special characters like [ ], ( ), &, #, *, !, %, $, £, may have unexpected results and are not recommended. Do you still wish to continue to the next step?

*I understand this would have to be in the "has" field.*

Oh! Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Does this work? `(to:john@aol.com list:(123456.xt.local)) OR (to:peter@aol.com list:(7891011.xt.local))`. I think part of the problem might be the < and > signs. See here: [Gmail Search Operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190)

Comment: Those angle brackets are there just to show the separate statements in my example. I am not using those in my filter.